# swift - NSMangedObjectContext doesn't refresh data

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have two view controllers, first one to display a list of objects stored in CoreData and the second one to create new objects.

After a new object is created I return to the list of objects, but newly created object is not there. After I restart the application the new object is displayed. Here is my code:

**ListOfProjectsViewController:**

```
var projects:[ProjectItem] = []

lazy var managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        loadProjects()
    }

    func loadProjects() {

        do {
            let results = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
            projects = results as! [ProjectItem]

            tableView.reloadData()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "CreateNewProjectSegue" {
            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! CreateNewProjectViewController
            vc.project = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("ProjectItem", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as? ProjectItem
        }
    }
```

**CreateNewProject:**

```
let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
var project:ProjectItem?

@IBAction func saveAndCloseBtnPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        project?.title = projectTitleField.text
        project?.number = projectNmField.text
        project?.comments = projectCommentsTextView.text

        try! project?.managedObjectContext?.save()

        do {
            try self.managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
        }

        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you not using `performBlock` , or an `NSFetchedResultsController`?

Comment: Have you tried printing fetchRequest to make sure it's not nil?

Comment: yes, I checked it, it is not nil and it is run on a main thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)` is returning you a static array, so it won't update when the underlying data changes.

You should use a `NSFetchedResultsController` instead, then you can receive update notifications when something changes.

Comment: tried with NSFetchedResultsController, still the same result